# Flutter - Expected: should do the following in order: emits an event Empty, NumberTriviaError, Actual: Empty: Which was not a Stream or a SteamQue

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing Flutter Clean Architecture TDD course from closely 20days. I'm writing unit test of Stream (mapEventToState) here is my Test code :

```
test(
  'should emit [Error] when the input is invalid',
      () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockInputConverter!.stringToUnsignedInteger(SIGNED_STRINGS))
        .thenReturn(Left(InvalidInputFailure()));
    // assert later
    final expected = [
      // The initial state is always emitted first
      NumberTriviaEmpty(),
      NumberTriviaError(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE),
    ];
    expectLater(bloc!.state, emitsInOrder(expected));
    // act
    bloc!.add(GetTriviaForConcreteNumber(tNumberString));
  },
);
```

Just forget all about (when), because It's fine I've mocked all classes and simply return a Left of Either which is obviously a Failure. So the problem rise in expected data, I just created list of expected and passed it inside the method the "expectLater" in order "emitsInOrder".

My Implementation code of Stream is is here :

```
@override
Stream<NumberTriviaState> mapEventToState(NumberTriviaEvent event,) async* {
if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber) {
  final inputEither =
  inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);

  yield* inputEither!.fold(
        (failure) async* {
      yield NumberTriviaError(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
    },
    // Although the "success case" doesn't interest us with the current test,
    // we still have to handle it somehow.
        (integer) => throw UnimplementedError(),
  );
}
```

The [ Error ] I have put in the Title isn't completed because It's a little bit long I'm sharing it here please take a look upon It what actually I'm doing wrong.

```
Expected: should do the following in order:
      • emit an event that NumberTriviaEmpty:<NumberTriviaEmpty()>
      • emit an event that NumberTriviaError:<NumberTriviaError(Invalid Input - The number must be a positive integer or zero.)>
 Actual: NumberTriviaEmpty:<NumberTriviaEmpty()>
 Which: was not a Stream or a StreamQueue
```

I have done all these the same, what it expect from me but still it's throwing this exception. I stuck in this error about 4 days I search everywhere but I didn't find any fix, Kindly If I'm doing something wrong just throw your recommendation in the comment section or Answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to changing 'bloc!.state' to 'bloc' (per QuangNV and ouflak), try also changing the 'async' in your test to the [asynchronous generator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators), 'async*', to match to the code used in your Stream implementation.

```
test(
  'should emit [Error] when the input is invalid',
      () async* {
    // arrange
```

Comment: you have no idea how much it helped. I was getting desperate not to get this resolved soon. :)

Comment: Regarding `async*` don't do this. It does get your test passing. It essentially silently disables your test. Put in an explicit failing expectation and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @NicoSpencer I have added expect(1,2) inside async*, the test still passes, as you said. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @mondayrris I would need to see what test you're trying to run however a common problem with the `emits` matchers is that the objects you're asserting do not properly implement `==` and `hashCode`. If you're instantiating a new object in your `emits` list and they don't implement equality correctly, you're not going to match correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**I used another way by using the bloc_test: ^8.0.0 package and the flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0**

```
  blocTest<NumberTriviaBloc, NumberTriviaState>(
    'should emits [LoadingState, ErrorState(InputConvert failure..)] when add event [getConcreteNumberTrivia] with invaildString ',
    build: () => numberTriviaBloc,
    setUp: () => when(mockInputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(any))
        .thenReturn(const Left(InvalidInputFailure())),
    act: (bloc) =>
        bloc.add(const GetConcreteNumberEvent(number: tNumberString)),
    expect: () => [
      LoadingState(),
      ErrorState(message: const InvalidInputFailure().message)
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

So the complete answer is

You can try changing from:

```
expectLater(bloc!.state, emitsInOrder(expected));
```

To:

```
expectLater(bloc, emitsInOrder(expected));
```

In addition to changing 'bloc!.state' to 'bloc' (per QuangNV and ouflak), try also changing the 'async' in your test to the asynchronous generator, 'async*', to match to the code used in your Stream implementation.

```
test(
  'should emit [Error] when the input is invalid',
      () async* {
// arrange
```

Answer (score 1):

> This solution uses flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2

It is important to have a glance at comment on every single solution. Thanks to Nico Spencer.

**Problem 1**: The initial state `NumberTriviaEmpty()` is never emitted by just calling:

```
bloc!.add(GetTriviaForConcreteNumber(tNumberString));
```

From now on, instantiating a new bloc WILL NOT automatically emit the initial state.

Therefore the expected StreamQueue should be:

```
final expected = [
  NumberTriviaError(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE),
];
```

**Problem 2**: `bloc!.state` is not a `Stream` or `StreamQueue`.

To fix this, use `bloc!.stream`.

And the final solution is:

```
test(
  'should emit [Error] when the input is invalid',
  () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockInputConverter!.stringToUnsignedInteger(SIGNED_STRINGS)).thenReturn(Left(InvalidInputFailure()));
    // assert later
    final expected = [
      NumberTriviaError(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE),
    ];
    expectLater(bloc!.stream, emitsInOrder(expected));
    // act
    bloc!.add(GetTriviaForConcreteNumber(tNumberString));
  },
);
```

Do not forget to rewrite the bloc content as:

```
const String SERVER_FAILURE_MESSAGE = 'Server Failure';
const String CACHE_FAILURE_MESSAGE = 'Cache Failure';
const String INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE = 'Invalid Input - The number must be a positive integer or zero';

class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  late GetConcreteNumberTrivia getConcreteNumberTrivia;
  late GetRandomNumberTrivia getRandomNumberTrivia;
  final InputConverter inputConverter;

  NumberTriviaBloc({
    required GetConcreteNumberTrivia concrete,
    required GetRandomNumberTrivia random,
    required this.inputConverter,
  }) : super(NumberTriviaEmpty()) {
    getConcreteNumberTrivia = concrete;
    getRandomNumberTrivia = random;

    on<NumberTriviaEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber) {
        final inputEither = inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);

        inputEither.fold(
          (failure) => emit(const Error(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE)),
          (integer) {},
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Lastly, when an asterisk(*) is added to `async`, it will become `async*` async generator and as a result the whole test is suppressed, which is not appropriate at all.

```
test(
  'should emit [Error] when the input is invalid',
  () async* {
...
    // Using async generator 'async*' does get your test passing. It essentially silently disables your test.
    expect(1, 2); //<--- An explicit failing expectation is put. Test still passes.
    final expected = [
      const Error(message: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE),
    ];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing from:

```
 expectLater(bloc!.state, emitsInOrder(expected));
```

To:

```
 expectLater(bloc, emitsInOrder(expected));
```

Hope you can solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also following the same course & in addition of the ) async* { suggestion, I also needed to add quotation marks to have
yield Error(message: "INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE");

In contrast,
expectLater(bloc.state,
expectLater(bloc!.state,
expectLater(bloc,
had not impact on passing the test successfully.